# Is the quotient of a complete ring, complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

> If $(R,\mathfrak m)$ is a complete local ring (with respect to the $\mathfrak m$-adic topology) and $I$ a prime ideal in $R$, is $R/I$ complete (with respect to the $\mathfrak m/I$-adic topology)?

It seems too strong, but I am unable to give a counterexample.

Comment: What you'd like to be able to do is take a Cauchy sequence in $R/I$, then lift each element so that you have a Cauchy sequence in $R$, then take the limit and push it back down to the quotient. So the question becomes: under what conditions can you lift your Cauchy sequence mod $I$ to a Cauchy sequence in $R$?.

Comment: The completion functor from the category of $R$-modules to the catogory of $\hat R$-modules is exact. So the quotient by an ideal $I \subset R=\hat{R}$ is complete if and only if $I$ is complete as an $\hat R$-module. I tend to think that this is always the case at least for Noetherian $R$.

Comment: A remark is that, conversely, all complete Noetherian local rings containing a field are of the form $k[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]/I$ (Cohen structure theorem).

Answer (score 13):

**Proposition.**
Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a complete Noetherian local ring.
Let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$.
Then $(R/I, \mathfrak{m}/I)$ is complete.

*Proof.*
The following sequence of $R$-modules is exact

$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0.$$

Since $R$ is Noetherian, the following sequence is exact

$$0 \rightarrow \widehat{I} \rightarrow \widehat R \rightarrow \widehat{R/I} \rightarrow 0,$$

where $\widehat I$ etc. are the completions of $I$ etc. with respect to $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology.

Since $R$ is complete, $\widehat R = R$.
It is well known that $I$ is a closed submodule of $R$ with respect to $\mathfrak{m}$-adic toplogy. Since $R$ is complete, so is $I$, hence $\widehat I = I$.
Therefore we get the following exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow R \rightarrow \widehat{R/I} \rightarrow 0,$$

hence $R/I$ is complete.