# Dimension of quotients and localizations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This quesion arises in particular from algebraic geometry: I have the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,0}\simeq k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ in the affine plane and I am interested in the dimension of specific quotients.

Let $f,g\in k[x,y]$ be two polynomials, is the following true (we talk about the vector space dimension over $k$):
$$
\dim k[x,y]_{(x,y)} / (f,g) = \dim k[x,y]/(f,g) = \dim k[[x,y]] /(f,g)?
$$

Asked differently: Is the vector space dimension of the completion of $R$ the same as of $R$? What about the dimension of their quotients with any ideal?

Edit: Adding a bit more details: If $f$ and $g$ have a common zero in the point $(a,b)$, how about replacing the localization by $(x,y)$ by localizing by $(x-a,y-b)$?

Comment: @LegNaiB Important question: are you asking about Krull dimension of rings, or dimension of these vector spaces over $k$, the base field?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I talk about dimension over vector spaces, so in my calculations I would have $\dim C[[x]]=\infty$.

Comment: I work only with dimensions in $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\infty\}$, so these dimensions should all be equal if they are finite and if any dimension is infinite (no matter what type of infinity), then all the others should be as well infinite

Comment: I removed the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, every time I say $\dim$ here I'm talking about the dimension of a vector space over the base field $k$.

Equality 1: $\dim k[x,y]_{(x,y)} / (f,g) = \dim k[x,y]/(f,g)$. Take $f=x-1$, $g=y-1$ to see that the LHS is $0$ ($f$ and $g$ are both units, so $(f,g)$ is the whole ring) while the RHS is $1$. So this does not hold in general.

Equality 2: $\dim k[x,y]/(f,g) = \dim k[[x,y]] /(f,g)$. Take $f=y$, $g=y-x^2+x$ to see that the LHS is $2$ while the RHS is $1$ ($(f,g)=(y,x-x^2)$, but $x-x^2=x(1-x)$ and $1-x$ is a unit in the power series ring, so $(f,g)=(y,x)$). So this does not hold in general.

Equality 3: $\dim k[x,y]_{(x,y)} / (f,g)=\dim k[[x,y]] /(f,g)$. Take $f=g=x$ to see that the LHS is of countably infinite dimension over $k$ while the RHS is of uncountably infinite dimension over $k$. So this does not hold in general.

---

The salvageable statement here is that if $V(f)$ and $V(g)$ do not share a common component through $(0,0)$, then $\dim k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(f,g)=\dim k[[x,y]]/(f,g)$. To prove this, the condition "does not share a common component through $(0,0)$" translates to $(f,g)_{(x,y)}$ not being contained in any principal ideal of $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$. Therefore it must either be the whole ring or an ideal of height two. In the first case, this means $(f,g)\subset k[[x,y]]$ is also the whole ring, so both sides are zero. In the second case, $(f,g)_{(x,y)}$ has radical $(x,y)_{(x,y)}$, and so $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(f,g)$ is an Artinian local ring. Since every such ring is already complete with respect to its maximal ideal, $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(f,g)\cong k[[x,y]]/(f,g)$ and therefore they must have the same dimension as $k$-vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the details! If I only work with $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\infty\}$, so it doesn't matter which type of infinity we have, is Equality 3 then correct?

Comment: I think I mean dimension over $k$ as well, so that e.g. $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/((y-1)^2, x^2-y)=4$ as the generators are $1,x,y,xy$. This is the dimension over $k$, right?

Comment: Yes, except for the fact that you've computed that example wrong: $(y-1)$ is a unit in $\Bbb C[[x,y]]$.

Comment: But $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y-1)}/((y-1)^2,x^2-y+1)$ would have dimension $4$?

Comment: Yes, it would have vector space dimension four: by rewriting every instance of $y-1$ as $-x^2$ via $x^2-y+1=0$, it has basis $1,x,x^2,x^3$.

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I can then work just with $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ as I did before. Seemingly my calculations with the latter were wrong either way (as the above comment shows).

Comment: But this means there is no simple way to somehow switch between $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ and $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ without changing dimension?

Comment: I don't understand your sudden objection - did you not read the last paragraph of my answer? If $\sqrt{(f,g)_{(x,y)}}=(x,y)$, then $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(f,g)\cong k[[x,y]]/(f,g)$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm a bit confused about the whole topic, sorry about that. One (probably) last question: $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ and $k[[x,y]]/(f,g)$ are not isomorphic, because if we choose $f=g=0$, we would get the two vector spaces, but the radical is not $(x,y)$ and thus the quotients are not isomorphic, right? I would give you more than 1 upvote for your continuous help :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ is not isomorphic to any quotient of $k[[x,y]]$ (the former is not complete, but any nonzero quotient of the latter is complete, cf [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117589/is-the-quotient-of-a-complete-ring-complete)). Is that really what you want to ask about?

Comment: I'm currently working on my thesis and I assumed that $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}\simeq k[[x,y]]$, which is unfortunately not true. Therefore, I try to save as much of the calculations I did with $k[[x,y]]$ and try to transfer them to the correct vector space $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$. So yes, it is what I'm asking about. But I think it is clear now and everything I calculated on $k[[x,y]]/(f,g)$ can be transferred to $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(f,g)$ if $f,g$ are valid as in your answer (and they are)